# Apache Ignite - async IO and pessimistic transactions

Tags: java, ignite

I'm a bit puzzled by the transaction model in Ignite, where an operation is associated with a transaction by the thread. The happy path therefore is to:

- Start a transaction
- Do operations (`get` or `put` data)
- End the transaction...

...when all of the above happens in one thread.

But how to use the async IO in this case then, i.e. `putAsync` and `getAsync`? After the first call to any of it I'd like to release the thread for the subsequent events, which won't be related to the transaction I started.

Or in general - how to use multiple threads with such transactions - say reactive streams implementations (RxJava or Project-Reactor) where where events might be handled in different threads?

There is a nice couple of method that seem like what might help: `Transaction::suspend` and `Transaction::resume`, which can transfer a transaction along the threads. These methods even seem to work in my scenarios with pessimistic transactions. However, their javadoc says:

> Supported only for optimistic transactions.

Like I said, I didn't find it true - `suspend` and `resume` seem to be working like a charm for the pessimistic ones too so far... So, maybe the javadoc is incorrect? And if it still is correct, how could I use a pessimistic transaction from multiple threads?

Thanks!

Comment: While the main question seems to be about suspend/resume for pessimistic transactions, and I'll leave this to someone more familiar with these internals. But to answer the more general question: yes, Ignite 2.x generally ties transactions to threads which is easy with traditional programming but complicates things with continuations and reactive programming. Ignite 3.0 (in beta as of Aug 2023) changes transactions API - transactions are no longer bound to a thread, specifically to support reactive style. BTW community will be happy to hear feedback on that! ;)

Comment: Thanks @StanislavLukyanov! Great to know that Apache 3 addresses this. Do you know what's the expected timeline for releasing it?